# Loop with 2 successive same exit code

Tags: bash, until-loop

I poll a string from an app API that matches with `true` or `false` to take further actions.

```
until curl.../connections|awk -v LID=$LinkID '$0~LID,/}/ {if ($0~/connected/) print}'|grep -q 'connected true,'; do
sleep 5
done
if other condition; then exit 0
fi
while other statement; do
sleep 15
done
shutdown
fi
```

My problem is that the `false` value is not reliable from a single poll on the long run in certain circumstances, which leads to a premature `done`. I'd need the expression between `until` and `do` to be re-checked, say 5s after the first one, but I don't know how to this.

Please help

[EDIT] : not sure the title of the thread is well worded

Comment: One suggestion: Move the "bash" from the title to the tags. Also, I'm not sure I understand your question, can you describe the required and the current behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it this way (there are syntax errors everywhere but the main idea is here):

```
while true; do
 if [[ curl.../connections|awk -v LID=$LinkID '$0~LID,/}/ {if ($0~/connected/) print}'|grep -q 'connected true,' ]]; then ((++counter))
   if [ $counter -ge 4 ]; then
    break 1
    else sleep 15
    continue 1
   fi
  else
   counter=0; sleep 15
  fi
done
```

I had connections to kind of helper relay servers that lasted ~1mn before to die when the intended target was not present. It was just a question of timeout lenght